# dbus: problem with dbus_bus_get_unique_name

Tags: linux, dbus

I am having an issue with DBus:

1. I register with DBus *dbus_bus_get()* method : OK
2. I add filter matches : OK
3. I add a filter callback function: OK
4. I start a dispatch loop through *dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch()* : OK

Everything works OK.  Now, if I insert:

1a. *dbus_bus_get_unique_name()*

I get a nasty exception message:

> arguments to *dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block()* were incorrect, assertion "(error) == NULL || !*dbus_error_is_set ((error))*" failed in file dbus-connection.c line 3301.

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, it seems that the function **dbus_bus_get_unique_name()** must be called from within a specific context.  I managed to get a meaningful result when accessing this function through a **filter callback** function e.g. one registered with **dbus_add_filter** function.